# How to get all the 'tr' inside a 'table' in angularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a custom directive  that points to a 'tr' inside a table.

```
 <tr row-select >
```

I wants to remove a style from all tr under that particular table.

```
 directiveApp.directive('rowSelect', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function() {
                $('#db-conn-table tr').removeClass('info');
                element.addClass("info");
            });
        }
    });
```

Is that possible to do it without using **JQuery**?

```
$('#db-conn-table tr').removeClass('info');
```

Comment: Try `element.siblings().removeClass('info');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
app.directive('rowSelect', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function() {
            element.siblings().removeClass('info');
            element.addClass("info");
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/85fKQ/)